# MVVM CallerMemberName and "magic strings"

Tags: c#, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged, idataerrorinfo, callermembername

New C# 5.0 release introduced something to get rid of "magic strings" in INotifyPropertyChanged implementation like:

```
OnPropertyChanged("CustomerName");
```

Now it is possible to write just:

```
OnPropertyChanged();
```

It is possible due to CallerMemberName in method definition:

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{ ... }
```

It is much more refactoring friendly than "magic strings" way and faster than lambda expressions, but I wonder how can we call multiple times OnPropertyChanged from one set accessor. For example if we wanted something like this:

```
public int Width
{
    get
    {
        return width;
    }
    set
    {
        width = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Width");
        OnPropertyChanged("Height");
    }
}
```

How can we do this with CallerMemberName way and avoid using "magic strings" and lambda expressions?

I also wonder how can we avoid using "magic strings" in IDataError info:

```
public string Error
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {
                if (columnName == "Name")
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name))
                        Error = "Name cannot be null or empty.";
                    else
                        Error = null;
                }

                return Error;
            }
        }
```

I am new to MVVM so maybe I overlooked some clever way to deal with "magic strings", however I did some research and found nothing.

Comment: Why would you want to say that the height has changed just because the width has? Did you actually meant that to be something like "Size"?

Comment: It's just an example but sometimes one property may depend on the other. For example if width is always height*2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is, that you can't do that. As the name `CallerMemberName` indicates, it will contain the name of the caller.
For cases where you want to raise `PropertyChanged` for another than the current one, you will have to use one of the "old" ways.

In `IDataErrorInfo` you also have to use one of those ways, there is no alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is about C# 5.0, but if people still have questions of thise nature please check out c# 6.0. C# 6.0 Has a great way to solve this problem. Check out the nameof keyword. I wrote a little post about it if anyone is interested: [c# 6.0 solves magic strings problem](https://dannyvanderkraan.wordpress.com/2015/05/15/c-6-solves-magic-strings-problem/)

Answer (score -1):

This will help:
"Kind Of Magic"
Effortless INotifyPropertyChanged

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d5cd6aa1-57a5-4aaa-a2be-969c6db7f88a

as an example for adding it to one property:

```
[Magic] 
public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } } 
string _name;
```

Another example for adding it to all the class properties:

```
[Magic] 
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{ 
  public string Name { get; set; } 
  public string LastName { get; set; } 
  ..... 
}
```

Comment: -1; this is maybe a nice tool, but I don't think it's a solution for the OPs problem. If I'm mistaken, please improve your answer with some explanation.